# Adjective to describe a strikingly smart person (Prodigious?)

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I am a non-native speaker in need of a term to describe a strikingly smart person. That is, one who is extraordinary intelligent or has amazing abilities or qualities. I know that a `prodigy` is used as a noun to describe such persons and, during research, found:

`prodigious`

The definition, as given by oxforddictionaries.com, however, makes me unsure that 'prodigious' suits my needs:

> Remarkably or impressively great in extent, size, or degree:

How would a native speaker perceive the usage of prodigious in a context that implies that a character being described is of such strikingly smart nature, and are there any alternatives?

Please note that I know, for example, the term `ingenious` but would like to use something even more powerful to describe the utter outstanding nature of the character, if possible.

Comment: A [polymath](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polymath) is a person who has knowledge in a wide range of subjects, though it doesn't necessarily imply superior intelligence.

Comment: [Sage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sage) implies great wisdom, but not necessarily great intelligence.

Comment: Sharp is a commonly used word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Prodigious* would definitely not be understood in the way you would be meaning it if you apply it to a person directly, like

> Bob is truly prodigious.   *<sub>(not recommended)</sub>*

However, you could certainly use it to describe their intelligence, like so:

> Bob has a prodigious intellect.

If you simply want to say that someone is remarkably intelligent, I might recommend sticking with ***genius***:

> : a very smart or talented person : a person who has a level of talent or intelligence that is very rare or remarkable
>
> : a person who is very good at doing something
>
> : great natural ability : remarkable talent or intelligence
>
> *(from [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genius))*

While this is not an adjective, you could certainly use it descriptively, as in "He is a true genius".

Answer (score 0):

Consider **brainiac** that is a very intelligent and usually studious, erudite person.

Example: *Why brainiac? Brainiacs are extraordinary thinkers who think in a way most people are extraordinary thinkers who think in a way most people are unfamilar with. They think uncommon. Commonsense is so common that it does not make real sense to uncommon thinkers, it never did*. [source: Braniac's by Salah Habib](https://books.google.fr/books?id=2ycJjYRoG_MC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=Why%20brainiac?%20Brainiacs%20are%20extraordinary%20thinkers%20who%20think%20in%20a%20way%20most%20people%20are%20extraordinary%20thinkers&source=bl&ots=t93DZ4xHoS&sig=Uf1tdiCVzix3LMjPbWSyZyUAuak&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizqPagr_3KAhVJWRoKHWkuBA0Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Why%20brainiac%3F%20Brainiacs%20are%20extraordinary%20thinkers%20who%20think%20in%20a%20way%20most%20people%20are%20extraordinary%20thinkers&f=false)

Comment: Is that a quote from something?  I'm struggling to try and make sense of your example.  In my (native-speaker) world, "braniac" is usually reserved for sarcasm, like when somebody does something bone-headed..."That's just great, Braniac!"

Comment: @KristinaLopez -   Yes, "braniac" is often (mostly) use with a negative connotation. But, opposite to the books "for dummies", Thomson/Peterson's has published some [books "for brainiacs"](http://www.book-info.com/series/Brainiacs+Series.htm).

Comment: Gotcha. ( I found your quote online - you should cite its source)